# How do I manipulate a specific tooltip value of a Chart.js pie chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

I'm successfully displaying a Pie chart from `Chart.js`. If I hover the given slice, it will also return the label, as well as the value.

However, the value isn't very user friendly; I'd like to convert it to another value, more comprehensible for users.

How do I access the tooltip value for one given slice? I can only seem to get them all.

Sample code:

```
    this.examplePieChart  = new Chart(ctx1,{
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: byteLabels,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'bytes',
                    data: BytesArr,
                    backgroundColor: defaultChartColors,
                },
            ]
        },
        options: {
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'label',
            }   
        }
    });
```

I can access ALL the values of the tooltip data, my attempt was something like this:

```
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'label',
                callbacks: {
                    label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                        let tmpArr = [];
                        for(let i = 0; i < data.datasets[0].data.length; i++){
                            tmpArr.push(data.datasets[0].data[i].fileSize());
                        }
                        return tmpArr;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Where i run the `fileSize()` to convert Bytes to MiB/KiB. And it works - however, when hovering a slice, it will show ALL tooltips on any given slice, instead of the one I'm hovering.

How do I access the data value of a single given slice of a pie chart, and manipulate it? Currently, I can only access them all with the `data` value, which returns an entire array.

Without the callback above, I am successfully showing `label: value`, but I want to manipulate this specific value for each slice - not all values at once :o)

Answer (score 0):

in the end, it could be accessed as such:

```
        tooltips: {
            mode: 'label',
            callbacks: {
                         const currentValue = dataset.data[tooltipItem.index];
                         return currentValue.fileSize();
                }
            }
        }
```